# How do I limit the length of the array returned by a function equals to the length of the incoming argument + 1 in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How do I limit the length of the array returned by a function to the length of the incoming argument + 1 in TypeScript?
I have a function called `useLoading` that can be passed multiple functions that return a promise and return `[loading, ...fetchFns]`, where the length of `fetchFns` is the same as the length of the incoming argument.
The effect I wanted to achieve was that

```
const [loading, cb1, cb2, cb3] = useLoading(fn1, fn2, fn3); // GOOD
```

And in this way, TS will find the error in time.

```
const [loading, cb1, cb2, cb3] = useLoading(fn1, fn2); // cb3 is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
function useLoading<
  T extends ((...args: any) => any)[]
>(...args: [...T]): [boolean, ...T] {
  return null!
}
```

`useLoading` has a generic parameter `T` which holds a *tuple* of all the functions passed via `args`. We use the [variadiac tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) syntax to force TypeScript to narrow the passed array to a *tuple* type. The same syntax can also be used for the return type. We return a *tuple* where the first element is a boolean and rest are `...T`.

```
const [loading1, cb1, cb2, cb3] = useLoading(() => {}, () => {}, () => {}); // GOOD
const [loading2, cb4, cb5, cb6] = useLoading(() => {}, () => {}); 
//                         ^^^ Tuple type '[boolean, () => void, () => void]' of length '3' has no element at index '3'
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=120&pln=8&pc=101#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQQM4FMAySCGAJglAOYA8AKqlgB5xZSEaoAUrAdF-gE6kYAuVPigBPAJSoAvAD5hY8QG0AujM7c%20g1Iq4dKy8UMUAjJEgA2WEQBpUu-agDeoVKh5Y4EHmigRz5gEJQAF9QUBgUDDhtcwJiMgBGWxhjJNQUgCZk4wBmZWl0bDwiElJ2SVknYNtWCrlHarY6qvEAblQAeg7UAHEAeT6AEXDI6MVYkrIs9OMAFmyAVmyANnypQtw40vLpesba3Zb20C7XM-OLy4uAPVvUSggAB0tUOFFHrFQAchMzSxsmocAG5IBCEGrNEFg5RfVBIMCoSxkOAAC2%20OVhKPwLCgSBolgAtoxovhoiRCHR0V8gA)